# What is Config in Docker Compose (Preview) in Deployment Center of App Service for Container in Azure

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure App Service for Container. In the `Deployment Center` blade, I set up the `Source` to `Container Registry` and the rest of the Registry settings as follow (Note that I set the Container Type to Docker Compose Preview):

[image]

Since there's no documentation, no hint, my question is what is supposed to go in this Config text area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you paste or upload your Compose file using the **Choose File** button.

The infobox appears only when creating a new service.
[image]